# Constraints working correctly in simulator, but not applied in Xcode editor

Tags: ios, xcode

I am writing my first app using Xcode, and I've been working with constraints in a vertical stack view in main.storyboard. I applied constraints to center my stack view horizontally and vertically. I can see that the constraints are applied, and when I run the app in the simulator, the constraints are working as I intended. Back in main.storyboard, the constraints are not applied, so everything looks wonky until I run it in the simulator.

Is this just something I have to live with, or is there a way to "apply" the constraints so I can sort of preview them without actually having to run the simulator every time I add a new constraint to make sure it is working the way I wanted it to?

Answer (score 1):

Select **Editor > Update Frames**, or click the little round arrow icon at the bottom right:

[image: Update Frames Button]